# c++ array of parent class inside a child class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Assume I have two classes

```
class A{
    /*with some attributes and methods*/
};

class B{
    /*with some other attributes and methods*/
};
```

### My problem

I would like to have two things that seems to be mutually exclusive...

- `B` becomes a child of `A`. So I want to declare `class B:public A`.

But if I do that, `B` contains only "one set" of attributes of `A`

```
class B:public A{
    /*with some attributes and methods*/
};
```

- `B` has `N` different instances (an array) of `A`.

But if I do that, `B` doesn't know the method contained in `A` and I loose the class hierarchy I need.

```
class B{
    /*with some attributes and methods*/
    private:
        A* a;
        unsigned int N; /*number of instances A*/
};
```

I could of course combine the two, but this doesn't seem a good idea because `B` will contain `N+1` instances `A`. I mean by `+1` that all the arguments contained in `A` will be inherited in `B`.

Is there an elegant way to combine my two requirements?

Comment: You may just create an array of Bs (each B inherits from A). Or you change A's implementation (if possible) and separate data from logic; all member functions operate on an array of data (and probably take an additional index parameter) which a single A instance holds.

Comment: You need to ask which is true: B *is a* A or B *has many* A. Inheritance is generally used when a child object can be used in place of an ancestor, but with different or extended behavior. Sounds like instead you want a container.

Comment: Why do you need to derive B from A if they have a has-a relationship? Especially if it is a has-N relationship? Sounds like some refactoring may be needed.

Comment: I'm not aware of any prohibition on having an array of objects that you also inherit. while you would have N+1 sets you will have N anyway with the array so the +1 shouldn't be a memory issue. besides. the +1 will be accessed something like this B->property and the array will be accessed like this B->A[i].property so you aren't likely to accidentally confuse them

Comment: The Composite Pattern allows you to use a container of objects in place of a single object. This looks like it  might be what you want.

Comment: "But if I do that, `B` doesn't know the method contained in `A`... ." Do you mean you want `B` to have access to protected functions of `A`? Is that the _only_ reason you want `B` to inherit from `A` (rather than just contain objects of type `A`)? Or does "the class hierarchy I need" mean something else?

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues that are in play in your requirements.

1. Type inheritance.
2. Object composition.

They are not mutually exclusive of each other. In the fact, the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) is a classic example of using both in a sub-type.

When you say:

```
class A
{
};

class B : public A
{
   A* aList;
   int N;
};
```

You are using the classic Composite Pattern. If you change the names `A` and `B` to `Object` and `CompositeObject`, the picture will become clearer.

```
class Object
{
};

class PrimitiveObject : public Object
{
};

class CompositeObject : public Object
{
   Object* objectList;
   int N;
};
```

In this pattern, one of the objects in `objectList` can be a `CompositeObject`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something on the lines of

```
class AInterface
{
public:
   virtual void ChangeFoo() = 0;
};

class A : public AInterface
{
public:
  virtual void ChangeFoo()
  {
  }
;


class B : public AInterface
{
public:
   virtual void ChangeFoo()
   {
     for( A a : allAsOwnedBythis())
     {
         a.ChangeFoo();
     }
   }
};
```

So you never work with A or B but with `AInterface` which are implemented by both `A` and `B`

Answer (score 0):

you could make B a friend class of A, that way you could still have access to private members with the array.

```
class A {
    friend class B;
    ...
};

class B {
    A* a;
    int n;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant way of solving this - treating non-leaf classes, such as `A` and `B`, as if they were abstract (with or without actually *making* them abstract).

Here is what I mean - make `class C` with the portion that must be common for `A` and `B`. Then inherit both classes separately, like this:

```
class C {
    // The common parts
};
class A : public C {
    // Parts specific to A
};
class B : public C {
    // Parts specific to B
private:
    A* a; // Depending on your design, this could be C*, not A*
    unsigned int N;
};
```

This lets your `class B` inherit the parts that it needs to share with `class A`, without becoming an instance of `A`, and inheriting the `N+1`-th set of `A`'s attributes.